# Whats the difference between runtime and session in Google Colab?

Tags: google-colaboratory

Whats the difference between runtime and session in Google Colab?

I was using Colab recently and got confused between the following terms:

- Kernel
- Runtime
- Session

I have researched the internet but couldn't get much help, so posting here

Answer (score 3):

- Runtime is the virtual machine allocated to you by Colab on temporary
  basis with lifetime limited to 12 hours.

  - Session is http session accessing your Colab Runtime from browser. It
    disconnects after some inactivity timeout but this does not affect
    your Runtime - you can reconnect to it multiple times within the 12
    hour window. The temporary files are stored in Runtime virtual
    directory called "contents" and will persist from session to session
    until your Runtime is reset.
- Kernel is an operating system on which Runtime and all your commands
  executed.

Comment: Thank you so much Len, this is very helpful.

Comment: @yonarp you are welcome. Don't forget to approve my answer.